# Dynamic Box Model - Gazebo and ROS

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdformat, ros-noetic, ubuntu-20.04

guys. I'm new to ROS and Gazebo and was trying to do a project with Turtlebot3.
I was trying to add a box model and would like it to constantly move around the map. However, when opening the turtlebot3 map with the roslaunch command and in a terminal close to the box's model.sdf spawn, it does not appear in the world and is indicating in a pose that it will do -z in a pose at the viewpoint. Can someone help me?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.7" ?>
<sdf version="1.7">
  <model name="dynamic_box">
    <link name="box_link">
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.001</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.001</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <visual name="box_visual">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <box>
              <size>0.001 0.001 0.001</size>
            </box>
            <uri>__default__</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
    <joint name="box_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent>default</parent>
      <child>box_link</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1000000.0</lower>
          <upper>1000000.0</upper>
        </limit>
      </axis>
      <limit effort="10.0" lower="-0.1" upper="0.1"/>
      <dynamics damping="0.1"/>
    </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Comment: What pose did you spawn the model at? Also, you are unlikely to be able to see a 1 millimeter cube at the scale you show us in the image.